# Exception with 0 in comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers, boolean, zero

Hey my question is pretty basic, while I was playing around in the expresssion

3 and 3%3 == False returns True

BUT

0 and 0%3 == False returns 0

With other numbers instead of 0 the result is either True or False but never 0.

I wanted to know what does make 0 so special.

Answer (score 1):

From all integers, 0 is the only one that is evaluated to `False`. In fact, `False`'s value is 0 (you can try `print False + 0`) - so you get the second expression's result (`X % Y == Z` which is `True`/`False`).

Any other integer and the first argument is what is returned (`int`) since `and` stops and returns the first expression false-y expression (there is no need to proceed once you hit a single `False` in an `and` expression). It does not matter what the next expression is since it's never even evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

First, `3%3` is equal to `0`. Next, `bool` is a subclass of `int`, with `0==False` and `1==True`. Then, you have `3 and 3%3==False`, which is `3 and 0==False`, which is `3 and True`.

So now that leaves us with the way short-circuiting works: with `and`, if the first value is falsey, it returns the first value. If the first value is truthy, it returns the second value. Since `3` is truthy, it returns the second value, `True`.

```
3 and 3%3==False
3 and 0==False
3 and True
^ truthy
3 and True
       ^ returned
```

For the next one, `0%3` is the same `0` as in the previous one, which turns out the same. However, the first value, `0`, is a falsey value, so, since it's combined with `and`, the first value, `0`, is returned.

```
0 and 0%3==False
0 and 0==False
0 and True
^ falsey
0 and True
^ returned
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** Boolean operators in Python evaluate to the first value that unambiguously determines their value.

So, let's look at `3 and 3 % 3 == False`, which is equivalent to `3 and ((3 % 3) == False)`. An `and` expression has a boolean value of `True` only if both the values have a boolean value of `True`; otherwise it has a boolean value of `False`. First it checks `3`, which returns `3`, which has a boolean value of `True` (`bool(3)` is `True`). Then it checks `(3 % 3) == False`, which returns `True`, which of course has a boolean value of `True`. Now that the right side of the `and` has also been shown to have a boolean value of `True`, that's what is 'returned' by the `and` expression.

The reason that `0 and 0 % 3 == False` returns `0` is because the first value in the `and` expression is checked first. Since the first value is `0`, which has a boolean value of `False`, there's no need to check the rest of the `and` expression. So `0` is returned by the `and` expression.

Here's some code:

```
>>> x = 5 or 3
>>> print(x)
5
>>> 
>>> y = 0 and 7
>>> print(y)
0
>>> 
>>> z = 1 and 7
>>> print(z)
7
```

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen, I think you may have misunderstood me. `bool(something_true and something_true) == True`, `bool(something_true and something_false) == False`. Also, what do you mean by, "It's different `and` from the `and` in `if` sentence"?

Comment: I'm just using `bool()` to illustrate the boolean value.

Comment: I misunderstood your answer, sorry to bother.

Comment: No problem; I certainly don't mind having mistakes pointed out if they're there :).